# Entity Framework 4 Linq non Lazy Loaded .Include(), include a related entity of a child of the current entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have an Entity A which is related to entity B on a 1:M relationship.
B is related to C in a 1:M relationship.

A --> B
B --> C

**How do I go about including the collection of C when I include B on A?**

I have this:

```
return (from d in _contextProvider.GetContext<SomeContext>().GetObjectQuery<A>().Include("B")
                select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

I tried this but throws error because it thinks C is related to A and can't find the relationship.

```
return (from d in _contextProvider.GetContext<SomeContext>().GetObjectQuery<A>   ().Include("B").Include("C")
                select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
return (from d in _contextProvider.GetContext<SomeContext>().GetObjectQuery<A>().Include("B").Include("B.C")
select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: You don't need to `.Include("B")` when you are calling `.Include("B.C")`, B will be included as well anyway.